# Remote EJB in Domain mode WildFly

Tags: ejb, wildfly

We are trying to lookup a remote EJB across wildfly running in domain mode with two nodes.

The setup is like this:

Wildfly Node 1:

- Module A: EJB Client
- Module B: Remote EJB

Wildfly Node 2:

- Module A: EJB Client
- Module B: Remote EJB

The wildfly nodes are part of a single domain.

Now, if we lookup the remote EJB across the nodes, it should return the EJB from the same node first, if it is available. Only if, it is not available, should the lookup return EJB from other node.

We have configured the EJB as clustered.
The problem is that even if we use "java:global" binding, the lookup is always returning the EJB from other node.

What configuration are we missing?

Comment: Can you provide some informations about how did you configure your wildfly? Like: did you execute `addUser.sh`? Did you put the file jboss-ejb-client.xml in the client? etc...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried configuring the JNDI properties for your InitialContext before doing the lookup? You can create a properties file and load at the moment to instantiate your InitialContext, in this file you can define the primary and secondary host that will be used to get the proxy, you can define this by a properties file or programmatically.

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI